# Restrict access to a view using the pattern lock

Tags: android

I want to restrict access to parts of my Android application using a pattern lock control (just like the builtin Android lock). What is the best way to do this?

Comment: [check this pattern lock libraty android](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/android-lock-pattern/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say write your own pattern lock control.

- Extend the View class
- Override onDraw (to draw your UI)
- Override onTouchEvent to handle the user interaction.

I have recently done this myself but the I would need to tidy up the code before I would consider making it public on here.